# Example of group $G$ such that $Z(G)={1}$ but $Z(H)\ne {1}$ for some $H\leq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to think of an example of a group $G$ such that $Z(G)={1}$ but $Z(H)\ne {1}$ for some $H\leq G$.

I've been trying to work with $S_n$ since its center is trivial but I can't find a suitable subgroup. Is there an obvious one in $S_n$?

If not, what would be an example?

Comment: Have you tried a cyclic subgroup?

Comment: Just pick any $\sigma \in S_n$ and then let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup generated by $\sigma$, which is abelian, hence $Z(H) = H$.

Comment: Any nontrivial subgroup of $S_3$ should work, seeing as $S_3$ is the smallest non-Abelian group.

Comment: Or the group of rotations of $D_n$ when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 4):

The center of any cyclic subgroup would be the whole cyclic subgroup since cyclic groups are abelian, so $H=\langle (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ \ldots n)\rangle$ would work for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Take any finite group with trivial center ($S_n, or A_n$) and take $H$ to be Sylow-$p$ subgroups (some non-trivial subgroups); they could be non-abelian, but centers of $p$-groups are always non-trivial.